# Chrome not loading site correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome

So i have been working on my website for quite some time now, everything works fine. However with the last push I did, my site nolonger wants to load css... But its only for me, other people can load the site just fine and it looks normal...

How i see the site: http://prntscr.com/igb0g5

How others see the site: https://gyazo.com/59ae56c7e203885f490d1f559fe55008

Any reason I would be getting these problems?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? And is there any logged in / logged out difference between you and the others?

Comment: Or did you, by accident,  block any of the files from loading? Ad blocker, firewall etc.

Comment: Open your site in a private browser window. If it looks fine there, you're (most likely) good.

Answer (score -2):

If it's working fine for other people and it's an issue happening only on your computer. I would suggest to

Clear the cache in chrome and if it doesn't resolve, try uninstalling and reinstalling chrome

If the issue persists,

Try using Firefox and check if the issue happens. If the issue still happens you might want to check the firewall on your computer or the references in your code.